# Entity Framework: A better way to update lots of table records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am new at Entity framework, and curious what the best way would be to update all tables with records of new data. I have a method which returns a list of objects with updated records. Most of the information stays the same; just two fields will be updated.
Currently I created two ways of doing that update.
The first one is to get data from the database table and iterate from both `Lists` to find a match and update that match:

```
var previousDatafromTable= db.Widgets.ToList();
var newDataReturnedFromMethod =.......

            foreach (var d in previousDatafromTable)
            {
                foreach (var l in newDataReturnedFromMethod )
                {
                    if (d.id == l.id)
                    {
                        d.PositionColumn = l.PositionColumn;
                        d.PositionRow = l.PositionRow;

                    }
                }
```

The second one is:

```
 foreach (var item in newDataReturnedFromMethod )
            {
                var model = db.Widgets.Find(item.id);                
                model.PositionColumn = item.PositionColumn;
                model.PositionRow = item.PositionRow;              
            }
```

I am iterating through the updated data and updating my database table by ID.

So I am interested to know which method is the better way of doing this, and maybe there is an option in Entity Framework to measure the performance of these two tasks? Thanks for your time in answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is really efficient.

The first option loops through `newDataReturnedFromMethod` for each iteration of `previousDatafromTable`. That's a lot of iterations.

The second options probably executes a database query for each iteration of `newDataReturnedFromMethod`.

It's far more efficient to join:

```
var query = from n in newDataReturnedFromMethod
            join p in previousDatafromTable on n.id equals p.id
            select new { n,p };

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    pair.p.PositionColumn = pair.n.PositionColumn;
    pair.p.PositionRow = pair.n.PositionRow;              
}
```

EF doesn't have built-in performance measurements. You'd typically use a profiler for that, or the [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.